# Update WP install to WP network & it broke the DB connection

Tags: multisite, database, htaccess, wp-config

I was using this tutorial to update my WP install to a WP network: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

I updated my .htaccess and wp-config to the settings provided to me in the prompts and reloaded the WP admin to login again. From there, I got the error: Error establishing a database connection. I did not change any details for my database and I am wondering why this happened. It was working perfectly before I updated my wp-config.php and .htaccess.

My wp-config.php additions were:

```
define(‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);
define(‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true);
define(‘SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL’, true);
define(‘DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘casestudies.splashworldwide.com’);
define(‘PATH_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘/’);
define(‘SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE’, 1);
define(‘BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE’, 1);
```

The update to my .htaccess was:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

These were changes that were requested by the WP admin. I then tried to repair my databases via the admin, and got the following errors:

```
wp_1_posts: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_posts’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_comments: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_comments’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_links: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_links’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_options: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_options’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_postmeta: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_postmeta’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_terms: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_terms’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_term_taxonomy: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_term_taxonomy’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_term_relationships: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_term_relationships’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_termmeta: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_termmeta’ doesn’t exist
wp_1_commentmeta: Table ‘casestudies.wp_1_commentmeta’ doesn’t exist
```

What is wrong with my setup, and how can I get my database fixed and working with WP network? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `define('MULTISITE', true);`

I just tested this. I got `Error establishing a database connection.` without it.

Comment: YESSSSSS that worked!